# Page Breaks in Crystal reports by a condition

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have a report that gets printed in a paper that is half of “letter” page size. So in my Details section In the report I have Invoice details which includes products and prices.

If the products in the Invoice are greater than 5, I want to print the rest of the product details in the next page with the page footer.

How can I do this. Please help me, I’m new to crystal Reports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the section expert, click the "Details" section on the left. On the right, there is a checkbox for "New Page After". To the right of that, there's a button to enter a formula. (it has "x-2" and a pencil on it). Click it and then you can implement a formula that would suit your needs.

EDIT: Actually, it's even easier. Take a look at the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I came up with the following formula.But it does not work. What is I'm doing wrong?  if count({SPGET_SalesInvoiceNormal;1.ProductCode}) > 5 then true else false

Comment: Please take a look at the screenshot I've attached. It would make things even easier for you, no need to use a formula. Btw, the formula you mentioned above will always return the same value, which is the number of product codes...